# ssh-add when ssh-agent fails

Tags: ssh, keychain, ssh-agent

I am trying to write a script that makes use of {ssh,gpg}-agents effortless (like keychain, but I discovered it too late). This script will be run in a sensitive environment, so I set a timeout in order to remove the keys from the agent after some time.

I managed to write the spawn/reuse part but now, I want ssh-add to be called automatically when the user is opening a ssh connection if the agent has no proper key.

Is there any way to make ssh-agent call ssh-add on failure or something better ?

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing (assuming the key has a distinctive name)

I have a script in `~/bin/` (which is in my `PATH`)

```
!/bin/bash
if ! ssh-add -l | grep -q nameOfmyKey
then
    ssh-add -t 2h ~/path-to-mykeys/nameOfmyKey.key
fi
ssh  myuser@myserver.example.net
```

`ssh -l` lists all keys currently active in the agent.

The parameter `-t` ensures that the key is enabled for a restricted time only.